# laravel eloquent remove the last zero on integer ending in zero

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

i have this table 
Info

```
ID | tel1 | tel2 |
1  | 080  | 0000 |
```

when i run `Info::all();` 
the output is
tel1 = 08,
tel2 = 0,

i need to remain the zero at the end of the data;

my table structure

```
tel1 mediumint(3) unsigned zerofill
tel2 mediumint(4) unsigned zerofill
```

im using laravel

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correct those columns are phone numbers. Also if its number it could contain in future some '+' sign or '(' and ')'. Try to store them better as VARCHAR instead of Integers.